# Export button is not visible with django-import-export package

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-import-export

I am trying to use django-import-export module in my admin and here are my settings

**admin.py**

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportMixin, ImportMixin, ExportActionModelAdmin, ImportExportActionModelAdmin

class RegistrationAdmin(ImportExportActionModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'activation_key_expired')
    raw_id_fields = ['user']
    search_fields = ('user__username', 'user__first_name', 'user__last_name')

admin.site.register(RegistrationProfile, RegistrationAdmin)
```

With the above code, i can able to see an *`Import`* button in admin as below

[image]

But i can't able to see Export option, so what's the problem what am i missing here ?

I have seen some ticket about export button permission here
https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/38 ? can anyone please let me know what need to be done in order for *`Export`* to appear ?

By the way i am using *`django suit`* as my admin theme

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`ImportExportModelAdmin`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_admin.html#import_export.admin.ImportExportModelAdmin)

[`ImportExportActionModelAdmin`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_admin.html#import_export.admin.ImportExportActionModelAdmin) only adds the export to the list of things you can do to selected items (see the dropdown in your screenshot)

Docs for `ImportExportActionModelAdmin` state

> Export functionality is implemented as an admin action.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **ImportExportModelAdmin**

Eg:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Question, Choice
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin


# Register your models here.

@admin.register(Question)
class ViewAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass


@admin.register(Choice)
class ViewAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass
```